# Openshift stucks in ContainerCreating. Generated from default-scheduler. Successfully assigned

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, deployment, connection, openshift

I have a project managed with `kubernetes`. The project is (among other various configurations), a back-end connected to a `mysql`.
It is working in a development environment. We had the problem today, when the connection to the database stopped working.
I began to investigate `openshift` to see if I found the solution and I saw that the `DeploymentConfig` mounted by `mysql` was not working, so I decided to restart this Deployment.

When I restarted it, it's stuck in the permanent '`ContainerCreating`' state, and it's not able to go any further than this.
I have removed the previous `pod` (the one that stopped working) and right now I only have this one left, which does not finish lifting.

Why could this problem be happening?

This is my current pod description from openshift with:

```
oc describe pod mysql-1-32wk
    Name:           mysql-1-32wk
    Namespace:      mynamespace
    Priority:       0
    Node:           openshift-9kaqj-worker-b-4xpgm/10.10.0.31
    Start Time:     Wed, 29 Mar 2023 12:47:48 +0200
    Labels:         deployment=mysql-1
                    deploymentconfig=mysql
                    name=mysql
    Annotations:    openshift.io/deployment-config.latest-version: 1
                    openshift.io/deployment-config.name: mysql
                    openshift.io/deployment.name: mysql-1
                    openshift.io/scc: restricted
    Status:         Pending
    IP:
    IPs:            <none>
    Controlled By:  ReplicationController/mysql-1
    Containers:
      mysql:
        Container ID:
        Image:          image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/openshift/mysql@sha256:a58f67c38d33d47b46c7aa3d75e90296bfb38b73226b011afbed2e430738c45c
        Image ID:
        Port:           3306/TCP
        Host Port:      0/TCP
        State:          Waiting
          Reason:       ContainerCreating
        Ready:          False
        Restart Count:  0
        Limits:
          cpu:     300m
          memory:  1Gi
        Requests:
          cpu:      100m
          memory:   100Mi
        Liveness:   exec [/bin/sh -i -c MYSQL_PWD="$MYSQL_PASSWORD" user -u $MYSQL_USER ping] delay=30s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
        Readiness:  exec [/bin/sh -i -c MYSQL_PWD="$MYSQL_PASSWORD" user -u $MYSQL_USER ping] delay=5s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
        Environment:
          MYSQL_USER:           <set to the key 'database-user' in secret 'mysql'>           Optional: false
          MYSQL_PASSWORD:       <set to the key 'database-password' in secret 'mysql'>       Optional: false
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'database-root-password' in secret 'mysql'>  Optional: false
          MYSQL_DATABASE:       <set to the key 'database-name' in secret 'mysql'>           Optional: false
        Mounts:
          /var/lib/mysql/data from mysql-data (rw)
          /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-zks1z (ro)
    Conditions:
      Type              Status
      Initialized       True
      Ready             False
      ContainersReady   False
      PodScheduled      True
    Volumes:
      mysql-data:
        Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
        ClaimName:  mysql
        ReadOnly:   false
      kube-api-access-zks1z:
        Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
        TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
        ConfigMapName:           ca.crt
        ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
        DownwardAPI:             true
        ConfigMapName:           ca.crt
        ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    QoS Class:                   Burstable
    Node-Selectors:              <none>
    Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
    Events:
      Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
      ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
      Normal  Scheduled  13m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned mynamespace/mysql-1-32wk to openshift-9kaqj-worker-b-4xpgm
```

This is my status showed from `Openshift`
[image: Pod details from Openshift]

Comment: Try sharing the mysql pod logs. Not starting, it means that there is something in the configuration that it doesn't like or that something has happened to the Volume it mounts (did you check that the PVC exists?).
On the Kubernetes side, if it schedules the pod and tries to start it, everything is most likely ok.

Comment: Check the `DeploymentConfig` Events.

Comment: Check that the cluster nodes are healthy